# VB6+SQL-Server: How can I execute a Query with named parameters using ADODB.Command?

Tags: sql-server, vb6

I've been trying to execute a parametrized query with ADODB.Command. I know I can use "?" for parameters, but my queries are rather large and I really don't want to track the exact order of the parameters. I tried something like the following:

```
objCmd.CommandType = adCmdText
objCmd.CommandText = "SELECT ... WHERE field1=@p_Field1 ...."    
Dim objParam As ADODB.Parameter
Set objParam = objCmd.CreateParameter("@p_Field1" ...)
objCmd.Parameters.Append objParam
...
objCmd.Open
```

It works for stored procedure parameters (setting CommandType = adCmdStoredProc, obviously), but I can't do this inside a Stored Procedure because of the dynamic nature of the query itself. When I try to run the query, I get the error:

```
 Must declare the scalar variable "@p_Field1"
```

Is there any other way around this that doesn't involve using stored procedures or (argh) concatenating the parameters values in the query itself and not use parameters at all?

Comment: @podiluska answer below works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this, to allow you to reuse parameters

```
objCmd.CommandText = "declare @var1 int, @var2 int, @var3 int; " & _
    "select @var1 = ?, @var2 = ?, @var3 = ?;" & _
    "select ... where field1 = @var1 or field4 = @var1 or field2 = @var2 ... "
```

and add the parameters in the normal ordered manner.

Comment: THIS APPROACH ACTUALLY WORKS!  In case it's not obvious why, they key is to first DECLARE them by name, and then SET (select @someVar=?,@SomeOtherVar=?) those named parameters using the stupid ADODB incoming by ordinal position notation, and then in the rest of your command text you can use those named parameters exactly as you would normally.  Beautiful.

Comment: I'm not using VB6 anymore (thank God...), but I marked the answer as accepted anyway because I've teen told the answer works.

Answer (score 6):

It's been quite some time since I used VB6, but have you tried setting the NamedParameters property on the Command object to True?

ie.

```
objCmd.NamedParameters = True
```

Answer (score 3):

So it looks like ADODB.Command doesn't really support named parameters.

Comment: um, YES it does. you need to have the correct ADO project references though. ADO 2.8 to be precise.  "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library" (msado15.dll). not sure about this one -  MAYBE you also need the reference "Microsoft ADO Ext 2.8 for DDL and Security" (msadox.dll)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how to do this is to create ? as the parameter e.g.

In you example:

```
objCmd.CommandText = "SELECT ... WHERE field1=@p_Field1 ...."
```

change it to:

```
objCmd.CommandText = "SELECT ... WHERE field1 = ?"    
objCmd.NamedParameters = True
Dim objParam As ADODB.Parameter
Set objParam = objCmd.CreateParameter("@AnyName",,,,Value)
objCmd.Parameters.Append objParam
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect, but...This is wrapper class I created that allows you to create Named Parameter queries...

### Below this code is a demo.  The biggest catch right now is that you must execute your setParameter statements in the correct order as declared.

```
Class SQLBuilder

Private Sub Class_Initialize(  )
    Set internal_commandObject = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
End Sub

Private internal_sql
Private internal_parameters
private internal_commandObject

Public Property Let CommandType(ByVal value)
    internal_commandObject.CommandType = value
End Property

Public Property Get CommandType
    CommandType = internal_commandObject.CommandType
End Property

Public Property Let Prepared(ByVal value)
    internal_commandObject.Prepared = value
End Property

Public Property Get Prepared
    Prepared = internal_commandObject.Prepared
End Property

Public Property Get SQLCommandObject
Set SQLCommandObject = internal_commandObject
End Property

Public Property Let SQLCommandObject(ByVal value)
Set internal_commandObject = value
End Property

Public Property Get CommandText
    CommandText = internal_commandObject.CommandText
End Property

Public Property Let CommandText(ByVal sqlStatement)
    GetSQLParameters sqlStatement
    internal_commandObject.CommandText =  internal_sql
End Property

Public Property Get Parameters
    Set Parameters = internal_parameters
End Property


Public Function SetParameter(name,datatype,direction,size,value)
 
 internal_commandObject.Parameters.Append internal_commandObject.CreateParameter(name,datatype,direction,size,value)
End Function 

Private Sub GetSQLParameters(sql)
    internal_commandObject.NamedParameters = true
    Set RegExObj = New RegExp

    With RegExObj
        .Global = true
        .Multiline = true
        .Pattern = "@\S+"
        .IgnoreCase = true
    End With
    
    Set internal_parameters =  CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With internal_parameters
        For each item in RegExObj.Execute(sql) 
        if Not .Exists(item.value) then  
            .Add item.value,item.value
        end if
        Next
        
    End With
    internal_sql = RegExObj.Replace(sql,"?")
End Sub


End Class
```

---

```
    Dim Temp
Dim mySqlBuilder 
Set mySqlBuilder = new SQLBuilder

With mySqlBuilder
    set .SQLCommandObject.ActiveConnection =PropConnection
.CommandText = "select LegalDescription from STAGE.DataLegalDescription where FISCAL_YEAR = @FISCAL_YEAR AND  AccountNumber = @ACCOUNT_NUMBER"
.Prepared = true
.SetParameter "@FISCAL_YEAR",adInteger,adParamInput,4, Cint(Year)
.SetParameter "@ACCOUNT_NUMBER",adVarChar,adParamInput,13, AccountNumber
End With

    RSProp.Open mySqlBuilder.SQLCommandObject
```

Comment: As far as I can tell this does not work, if cmd.commandType = adCmdText

Answer (score 0):

**this is important if you need to make use of namedparameters property:**
You need to have the correct ADO project references. ADO 2.8 to be precise.  "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library" (msado15.dll). not sure about this one -  MAYBE you also need the reference "Microsoft ADO Ext 2.8 for DDL and Security" (msadox.dll)

if you dont have 2.8 referenced, the compiler will complain to you it doesnt know what that property (namedparameters) is.
[image: your project references need 2.8 ADO]