# VB6 SQL Type Mismatch issues with Databases

Tags: sql, database, vb6

For my project, I have integrated a calculator which converts CM to FT. To make it worth more marks, I am trying to make it so that it will get the values and compare them against a Database to see which size Garage Door would be most suitable for the job

The SQL which purely searches for the value works. through and ADO which then only shows the found value on a data grid. But when I try to use the BETWEEN version, I get a Type Mismatch error which I have tried to fix by changing the variables to Integers and Reals, but it doesn't work. If anyone could help with this I would be really grateful!

```
Option Explicit
Dim sql As String
Dim sizeFindH As String
Dim sizeFindW As String  

Dim sizeFindHUp As Double
Dim sizeFindHDown As Double
Dim sizeFindWUp As Double
Dim sizeFindWDown As Double

feet = 30.48
heightCm = txtHeightCm.Text
widthCm = txtWidthCm.Text

txtHeight.Text = heightCm / feet
txtWidth.Text = widthCm / feet

heightFt = txtHeight.Text
widthFt = txtWidth.Text

sizeFindH = txtHeight.Text
sizeFindW = txtWidth.Text

sizeFindHUp = sizeFindH + 1
sizeFindHDown = sizeFindH - 1

sizeFindWUp = sizeFindW + 1
sizeFindWDown = sizeFindW - 1

sql = "SELECT * FROM  garageDoorSize WHERE ((garagedoorSize.height) BETWEEN '" + "%" + sizeFindHDown + "%" + "') AND '" + "%" + sizeFindHUp + "%" + "');"
sql = "SELECT * FROM  garageDoorSize WHERE ((garagedoorSize.width) BETWEEN '" + "%" + sizeFindHDown + "%" + "') AND '" + "%" + sizeFindHUp + "%" + "');"
```

The error Type Mismatch highlights this line of code, as I'm sure it would the next if I could fix it.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM  garageDoorSize WHERE ((garagedoorSize.height) BETWEEN '" + "%" + sizeFindHDown + "%" + "') AND '" + "%" + sizeFindHUp + "%" + "');"
sql = "SELECT * FROM  garageDoorSize WHERE ((garagedoorSize.width) BETWEEN '" + "%" + sizeFindHDown + "%" + "') AND '" + "%" + sizeFindHUp + "%" + "');"
```

Comment: Why are you using percent signs in the query?   What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: VB6 will let you use the `+` symbol for concatenation, but don't do it. Use the `&` ampersand symbol instead. That way VB6 knows you want concatenation and not addition.

Comment: I'm really new to SQL and read online that I should use the % for LIKE SQL statements, and thought it would be okay to keep them in for BETWEEN.. Thank you for the clarification though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code in the SQL statement is that you are using an extra parentheses before the `AND` operator. It's not a logical operator here combining 2 conditions.. It's part of the `BETWEEN` clause and shouldn't have parentheses before. Also the `%` shouldn't be used here as others said. 
Also the single quote is only used with strings.. So as long as your fields are numbers you shouldn't use it.

Oh.. And there's an extra parentheses without an opening one at the end of the query.

So your SQL should look like this:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM garageDoorSize WHERE (garagedoorSize.width) BETWEEN " & sizeFindHDown & " AND " &  sizeFindHUp & ";"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to concatenate a number and a string, hence the Type mismatch exception . Use `CStr` to convert the numbers to strings.

Also, I think you don't need the % signs, which are used with LIKE comparisons.

Also, as @jac correctly pointed out, use & to concatenate strings, not +. Edited my example to reflect for future readers of the post..

Try

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM garageDoorSize WHERE ((garagedoorSize.height) BETWEEN '" & CStr(sizeFindHDown) & "') AND '" & CStr(sizeFindHUp) & "');"
```

Note: Your code style of adding values direct to sql strings is vulnerable to sql injection (although not in this case as they are numbers). If these were strings, and came from user input your database and application is not secure. Best practice is to us sql parameter objects for your values... See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109826/vb6sql-server-how-can-i-execute-a-query-with-named-parameters-using-adodb-comm), which shows usage. Note, first post I found, sure there are better guides out there :)

Comment: Thanks for this, but it still seems to give me back an error in a Message Box stating "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." and then goes on to give me a full Error message..

"Run-time error '-2147217913 (80040e07)':
Method 'Refresh' of object 'IAdodc' failed.

Comment: I'm really new to SQL so sorry if my code is a bit off, if there are any easier ways for me to do this, I would be grateful if you could guide me in that direction!